# Can't make an SSL Connection 

Tags: ssl, connection, limits

I'm using a device that's got GPRS media to connect to a PC running stunnel. On TCPIP connections, the number of sessions is limitless. However, when it comes to SSL connections, it   could only go as far as 1062 successful sessions. I've tried it like 3 times but makes no difference. I've checked the OpenSSL codes and I couldn't seem to find any code block that limits SSL connection to 1062. On SSL's point of view, is there anything that limits the number of connections?

---

Yes, I'm using a postpaid phone SIM, but there isn't any problem with TCPIP. It only happens with SSL connections. We've tried connecting to other PC's as well using same OpenSSL stunnel, but only ends up to 1062 connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you connecting via a phone provider - could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm not the only one having this kind of problem. I found out that Sun Java System Directory Server had a limit of opened ssl connection which only reached 1020  (FD_SETSIZE=1024). It was hardcoded though so you could obviously see the cause of the problem. In my case however, I couldn't seem to find the culprit... :(